# SSH to host machine not possible from network

Tags: 14.04, ssh, lan

My system running Ubuntu 14.04 is a part of a subnet (192.168.3.XX) and everything used to work all fine; but recently, no other system on this subnet can access my machine, though I can access every machine from my system. SSH, SCP and everything that follows does not work, however, sftp works.

However, systems on a different subnet, like 192.168.111.XX can access my system normally.

This problem has arisen only recently, and I haven't installed anything new (other than the regular Ubuntu updates).

Can someone guide me in resolving this problem?

Comment: Try **ping** to determine if it is SSH handshake/security or just connectivity.

Comment: ping works fine

Comment: nmap it from another computer and check if port 22 is open, you can also check in hosts.allow and hosts.deny files.

Comment: as I said, it is accessible normally from other subnets, so the ssh port is open. Will check the hosts.allow and deny files though.